# "single assignment" vs "no early return"

Tags: c++, coding-style, return, constants

I have an algorithm that is rather difficult to understand, so I have written it down in the form of single assignments to `const` variables, with lots of commentary in between explaining why I'm doing that. Whenever the algorithm rejects a solution, a `return` statement leads out.

The customer, on the other hand, requested that the method have no "early" return statements, which is a somewhat conflicting goal, as the only way I could use my `const` variables in this scenario is lots of nested `if` blocks.

Is there an elegant solution that would allow me to get the best of both worlds -- variables that are valid if they are in scope and still a somewhat flat hierarchy?

*EDIT:* The customer also frowns upon exceptions and `goto`. This is a hot path, implementing a decision tree that determines whether a proposed solution from a solution generator is both acceptable and better than the previous solution.

The scoping with nested ifs would look like

```
if(fulfills_condition_1(sol)) {
    double const some_quality = quality_function_1(sol);
    double const normalized_quality = normalize_quality_1(some_quality);
    if(fulfills_condition_2(normalized_quality) {
    {
        double const another_quality = ...
    }
}
```

My current approach looks like

```
if(!fulfills_condition_1(sol))
    return;
double const some_quality = quality_function_1(sol);
double const normalized_quality = normalize_quality_1(some_quality);
if(!fulfills_condition_2(normalized_quality) {
    return;

...

update_current_solution(sol);
```

Comment: These "no early `return`" types are annoying. If your method makes its arguments and return values clear, the details of the implementation should not be a concern. This knee-jerk approach to rejecting a valid method of implementing is often from paranoia. You use unit tests should exercise all branches and verify that they work correctly.

Comment: Wrap all your code inside a `try catch`, throw on failure, catch and return. Problem fixed.

Comment: Maybe the first part of your algorithm can assign a variable that captures a lambda, and the `return` line can call whatever lambda has been assigned? I doubt you're allowed C++11, though.

Comment: How many conditions are there?

Comment: Currently, 12, but it is expected that more will be added.

Comment: Applying const with no useful utility to every stack variable looks excessive. May be you should switch to a functional programming language if you want all variables to be const.

Comment: The rationale for the `const` is that each of these values describes a certain property of the solution currently being tested. Any later modification to this value would certainly be an error.

Comment: Do all 12 conditions refer back to the qualities computed for the earlier conditions, or is it just some of them? I would want to abstract the computation of each set of qualities and the use of them to test the corresponding condition into some kind of unit, and then loop over the 12 units with a continuation expression to say that the condition is fulfilled. But if the specification is a gigantic spaghetti of inter-relations between the different qualities then the code can't be all *that* much better.

Answer (score 5):

> The customer, on the other hand, requested that the method have no "early" return statements

This requirement doesn't make code any better in C++ world, provided destructors are used for clean up, as they normally should in C++.

It is only useful for C code to avoid clean up duplication all over the function with multiple returns. And this is exactly the style used for Linux kernel.

Comment: Not that `double` requires any cleanup in C either. "What if we need cleanup?" "Then multiple returns would be a nightmare, don't use them" "So what if we don't need cleanup?" "Don't use multiple returns, because if you did need cleanup it would be a nightmare"

Comment: @SteveJessop _"Don't use multiple returns, because if you did need cleanup it would be a nightmare"_ - this, again, doesn't quite apply to C++ because destructors are superior to manual clean up routines and try/catch/cleanup/rethrow (anti)pattern. "What if that function now throws?" "Don't use manual clean up then, use destructors".

Comment: agreed, my discussion was intended to apply to the case where this function is written in C. Where, as you say, cleanup code would be a compelling reason for a single point of exit.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to refactor the algorithm into several functions so that the code that should be missed oy by a return is put into a new function and the test is reversed. (However without exceptions I suspect this is less elegant than your original code)

So original

```
T algorithm_fn() {
  T result;
  ...
  if (x) {
    return result;
  }
  //do more
}
```

becomes

```
T new_func( // the const parameters ) {
    //do more
}

T algorithm_fn() {
  T result;
  ...
  if (!x) {
     result = new_func( // the const parameters );
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: One way to avoid exceptions is to return a `bool` result from these sub-functions to tell the caller whether or not the algorithm should continue. In my view it's less explicit, but sometimes you have to work around the customer's prejudice.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will fall into the "circumventing customer requirements" category, but you can use a do/while loop to break out of a code block that you only want to run once.

```
int foo()
{
    int value = 0;
    do
    {           
       if ( condition1 ) { ... }
       else { break; }
       if ( condition2 ) { ... }
       else { break; }
    } while ( false )  // the do/while loop is only run through once.

    // do whatever clean up etc is needed.

    return value;      
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd say this is one of the only structures where goto's are acceptable.
Instead of returning, assign a return value to a variable, than goto the end of the method with the return statement.

Comment: Problem is you can't assign to a `const`.

Comment: Do you seriously think this is a good idea, or just a way to circumvent the customer's requirements?

Comment: Alas, the coding guidelines also prohibit `goto`, as that could be used to skip variable initializations. :/

Comment: @JørgenFogh I seriously think this is a good idea and have used it in quite a few production projects.